# How to update PHP API and PHP API EXTENSION to use 20190902 instead of 20180731

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I am currently running `PHP 7.3.24-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2020 16:59:59) ( NTS )` and I am trying to install sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv extensions. They extension install correctly and I followed the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-the-drivers-on-ubuntu-1604-1804-and-2004 but pecl is installing the extensions in the 2019 folder instead of the 2018 folder. In my php info my API and API EXTENSIONS both are listed as the 2018. How do I go about updating what my API/EXTENSION point to in Ubuntu 18.04? Or is there another way to install sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv into the  2018 folder? Thanks!

I keep getting these errors when running `php -v`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had was that I also had php 7.4 installed which I was not using, but `phpize -v` showed that the files were set to be placed in the 2019 folder. So I ran `sudo apt-get purge php7.4-common` then I re-installed sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv using pecl and following the link I posed above.

NOTE: I did not need php 7.4 so I was okay removing it.